# UITableView won't scroll to certain position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,48) animated:NO];
```

I have a UITableView that has a a UIView in the header. My UITableView won't scroll to (0,48) unless animated: YES. I don't want it to animate.

Anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the UIView for the section header, you're using function:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

I suspect you invoke setContentOffset somewhere in viewWillAppear, but that function is called later. And I think it overwrites your contentOffset. ...not sure why it doesn't when animated is YES, but anyway, just put your setContentOffset into this function like this:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = nil;
    if (section == SEC_WITH_IMAGE_HEADER) {
        headerView = self.neededView;
    }   
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,48) animated:NO];
    return headerView;
}
```

Worked for me, hope so will for somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the method named **-scrollRectToVisible:animated**.

---

I misunderstand your question. So, what you want is to initialize the tableview with a shift of y-coordinate about 48 pixels ?

This will make the tableView begin from yPos 48.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(48, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Hope this can help you....

Comment: self.tableView won't respond to scrollRectToVisible

Comment: Sorry for misunderstand your question. I am curious about self.tableView.contenOffset = CGPointMake(0,48) works or not.